# repeats specific chars after String

Tags: regex, nlp

I'm using a named entity classifier to detect artists in text.  Currently I want to detect patterns in the text that repeatedly appear.

```
11.20.12 Dillon Francis + Clockwork / / / Trees .
11.24.12 Michael Woods / / / Lizard Lounge .
12.08.12 Flosstradamus / / / Lizard Lounge .
12.14.12 Mat Zo / / / Lizard Lounge .
12.31.12 New Years Eve with BT / / / Lizard Lounge .
```

In the text I can detect the following named entities:

```
11.20.12 Dillon Francis + Clockwork / / / Trees .
[Dillon Francis]
11.24.12 Michael Woods / / / Lizard Lounge .
[Michael Woods, Lounge]
12.08.12 Flosstradamus / / / Lizard Lounge .
[Lizard Lounge]
12.14.12 Mat Zo / / / Lizard Lounge .
[Lizard Lounge]
12.31.12 New Years Eve with BT / / / Lizard Lounge .
[Lizard Lounge]
```

I want to use Regex to detect if the pattern is repeating multiple times. So when Dillon Francis is found, I see that after the named entity special chars are used except , and . 
so it's

```
[named entity][special chars] [ words ] endline
```

How can I translate this to a regex?

What i've tried:

```
([named entity])*([^\\dA-Za-z : , \\. ]) 
[^(Dillon Francis)]*[^a-zA-Z0-9]
```

The output is a true or false.

Comment: I did'nt understand what you want in output...

Comment: If the sentence has [special chars] [ words ] after the  [named entity]. It than has to return a true or false

Comment: something like this ?
http://regex101.com/r/nT7wN8/1

Comment: ok then I copy it in an "Answer"

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :

```
^[0-9.]{8}\s(Dillon Francis|Michael Woods|Mat Zo)[ \/+]+([A-Za-z0-9 .]+)$
```

[Demo here](http://regex101.com/r/nT7wN8/1)